# Compute $(-3+4i)^{1+i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Compute $(-3+4i)^{1+i}$

Here is what I got. $z=-3+4i$ so $|z|=5$ and $\operatorname{arg}(z)=\pi -\arctan(-4/3)$

$$
\begin{align}
(-3+4i)^{1+i} & =e^{(1+i)(\log*-3+4i)} \\
& =e^{(1+i)(\log 5 +i (\pi -\arctan(-4/3)))} \\
& =e^{(1+i)(1.60944+i4068)} \\
& =e^{(-3.0004+i5.137327)} \\
& =e^{-3.0004(\cos 5.137327+i \sin 5.137327)}
\end{align}
$$

My professor tell me this answer is not correct, and there should be other values. I'm not sure what dis I do wrong in this problem. I wonder if anyone would check for me please.

Comment: It's because $arg(-3 + 4i)$ has infinitely many values. You only chose one argument of $-3 + 4i$.

Comment: oh, so it should be  $arg(z) =arctan(-4/3)+k\pi$?

Comment: You're close: it should be $\arg(z) = arctan(-4/3) + 2k\pi$, $k\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: More simply, for some fixed complex $w$ not an integer, in general there is no canonical way to define a function $z\mapsto z^w$ on the whole complex plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, $\arctan(-4/3)\approx -53.1301^{\circ}$ so in the correct quadrant it would be $\pi - \arctan(4/3) = \pi + \arctan(-4/3)$. For a moment, let's forget the exponential and focus on the $\log$ term. That is, 
\begin{align}
(1+i)\log(-3+4i) &= (1+i)\bigl[\log(5)+i\pi-i\arctan(4/3)+2i\pi k\bigr]\\
&=\log(5)+i\pi-i\arctan(4/3)+2i\pi k + i\log(5)-\pi+\arctan(4/3)-2\pi k\\
e^{(1+i)\log(-3+4i)}&=-5^{i+1}\exp\bigl[\arctan(4/3)-\pi(1+2k)\bigr]\bigl[\cos(\arctan(4/3))-i\sin(\arctan(4/3))\bigr]
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

let $$z = (-3 + 4i)^{1+i}, t =\cos^{-1}(-\frac35).$$  then

$\begin{align}\ln z &= (1+i)\ln 5e^{it}\\&=(1+i)\left(\ln 5 + i(t+2k\pi)\right)\\ &=(\ln 5 -t- 2k\pi)+i(\ln 5+t + 2k\pi).\end{align}$

finally, $$z = e^{\ln 5 -t- 2k\pi}\left(  \cos(\ln 5+t + 2k\pi) + i \sin(\ln 5+t + 2k\pi)\right)  = e^{\ln 5 -t- 2k\pi} \left(  \cos(\ln 5+t ) + i \sin(\ln 5+t )\right)$$